# Powershell can't find mapped network drive

Tags: powershell, batch-file, networking

I have a PowerShell script that runs a batch file on a server.

The batch file requires the use of a network drive to run.  If I manually map the network drive (right click on C: and click map network drive, etc.)  and then run the batch file, then the batch file runs fine.

I need to automate the whole process using Powershell.  I wrote a Powershell which first maps a network drive and then calls the batch file.   The Powershell script can successfully map the network drive.

But for some reason, when the batch file is called from the Powershell script, it cannot find the mapped network drive and I get an access error.

Below is the code; what am i doing wrong?  Thank you for your help:

```
$NetworkDriveBegin = '\\network-drive\location'   #Assume this value is correct
$pass=ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
#Assume Password and username are correct
$myCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("username",$pass)

Write-Output("Mapping   drive : " + $NetworkDriveBegin)
 $TestDrv = "X:"
New-PSDrive –Name "X" –Root $NetworkDriveBegin –PSProvider FileSystem  -Credential $myCreds –Persist

If (-not (Test-Path -Path $TestDrv)) {
    Throw "Could not map drive $TestDrv, Stopping Execution"
    Exit
 }

#Execute Batch Script  
$BatchFile = 'D:\Batch_File.bat'   # Assume the name is correct

& $BatchFile

$EndDate = Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss
Write-Output("End Time: $EndDate")
Write-Output("Batch File Ended")
```

Comment: Provided there are no other connections to that same server I have no problems with your code, do you any get error messages?

Comment: In your code you map the `X:` drive yet run the batch file from the `D:` drive?

Comment: The batch file uses a resource (file) located on the X: drive.  The batch file is located on the D: Drive.   Should I try to put a net: use drive in the batch file instead ?

Comment: Mapped drives went out of need over 20 years ago. One programmer decided to implement a network share as a drive. Write your program with full network paths.